# Bison: Debugging shift reduce conflicts

Tags: bison

I have a Bison grammar which is a proper subset of the [Haskell 2010 report's grammar](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/).
Bison reports there are 76 shift/reduce conflicts. Having gone through the output of states, I could only find 9 that were because of errors in my interpretation of the report.

Running a suite of GTest unit tests which **should** cover the lexical structures supported, 4 of the tests intermittently fail with an unexpected token error (for each failure it's the same unexpected token each time).

I ran the tests in a loop for about 8hrs overnight and these tests failed up to 3 times each.

Can anyone offer any suggestions of any option that may be available in Bison to help get out more debugging info to try and trace these?

I've enabled trace parsing but they fail so rarely finding relevant bits of info in the output becomes a very arduous task (it's a huge file!). Are there any tools available that might help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bison reduce/reduce, shift/reduce conflicts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333953/bison-reduce-reduce-shift-reduce-conflicts)

Comment: I don't think so, I'm not asking about reducing the shift reduce conflicts, as I tried to explain, I already looked into the shift reduce conflicts, there's no way I can see to avoid them.

Comment: But asking about recommendations for tools is off-topic in SO, so perhaps you need to improve the wording to get the kind of help you might need. You can avoid the conflicts by using the appropriate attributes in bison, such as left and right associativity without changing any rules.

Comment: I suppose that there is some element of randomness in the tests; otherwise, you should get consistent results. It seems like your best bet is to capture the strings which fail to parse, and then parse just those strings with the trace option, or with some action set which generates a parse tree.